# Android Google Maps setMyLocationEnabled(true)

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm working through a tutorial and my app is basically working except for one small detail. I have an Options menu to demonstrate things like showing the map as a Satellite view, zooming to specific places etc.

The tutorial has two menu options as shown below which effectively need to be used in the order shown in order to zoom the map to where I'm currently located. I wanted to make the first item redundant (getcurrentlocation) by adding in the same functionality into the second menu item (show current loaction) but this causes the app to crash.

Does anyone have any ideas why and how to overcome it.
My thanks.

Code snippet follows

```
    case R.id.menu_getcurrentlocation:
        // ---get your current location and display a blue dot---
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        break;

    case R.id.menu_showcurrentlocation:
            // Adding the next line breaks the app.
            // map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();
        LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),myLocation.getLongitude());


        CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));

        break;
```

Comment: OK so I've struggled to get my LogCat added to my post but have a workaround which works but doesn't quite resolve my Q about why calling map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); within the Menu options doesn' work.
My workaround is to shift the map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); to just after I've made my call to getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: Means your menu click event doesn't work? are you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: Indeed I am getting a Null Pointer Exception

Answer (score 3):

Initially when first time your `GoogleMap` loads takes some time and there fore `Location` will be null.

So for your both menu options check this way.

```
if(map!=null){
 map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}


if(map!=null){
    Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();

    if(myLocation !=null){
    LatLng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(),
            myLocation.getLongitude());


    CameraPosition myPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(myLatLng).zoom(17).bearing(90).tilt(30).build();
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(myPosition));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From developers doc,

> A GoogleMap can only be acquired using getMap() when the underlying
>   maps system is loaded and the underlying view in the fragment exists.
>   This class automatically initializes the maps system and the view;
>   however you cannot be guaranteed when it will be ready because this
>   depends on the availability of the Google Play services APK. If a
>   GoogleMap is not available, getMap() will return null.

- *This can happen if the fragment lifecyle have not gone through
  onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) yet.*
- *This can also happen if Google Play services is not available.*

Further pointing out,

> If Google Play services becomes available afterwards and the fragment
>   have gone through onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle),
>   calling this method again will initialize and return the GoogleMap.

As there is no indication that from where did you got your map and at exactly which method call so I assume that your `getmap()` is returning null. That means the map is not ready.  Either because the fragment is not ready or your are running on a device without Google Play services available.

See [getMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMap%28%29) for more info.