# Mylocation button dont show up

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, location

I'm using `Android Studio` and using a map activity my map shows up fine, but the `Mylocation` button in the activity doesn't show. My google play services are installed. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

}
```

Comment: @Skizo Users get notified when a new answer to their question has been posted, you don't have to notify them yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this line in your code, replace your old code for this one :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if (mMap != null) {
       //edit this
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


    if (mMap == null) {

        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//here's the button

        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}

}
```

Also you have to add this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

If my answer didn't help you, you can follow this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/) and do what it says step by step :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this for your `setUpMapIfNeeded()` method:

[Android Google Maps setMyLocationEnabled(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057833/android-google-maps-setmylocationenabledtrue)

Answer (score 0):

To enable the location on your Google Maps if the Google Maps is visible on the activity/fragment.

- Create an instance of the Google Map:

  ```
  GoogleMap googleMap;
  ```

  Inside your main activity that implements LocationListener
- Add this line in your code to see the My Location Button:

  ```
  googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  ```

Don't forget to add the permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

For more details please refer to this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/).