# setMyLocationEnabled is not working ( not localising me)

Tags: android, google-maps, localization, android-maps-v2

Am wroking with google map v2 on android and i set setMyLocationEnabled(true)

but there is no action or anything , it doesn't locate.

here is a part of my code , how can i fix it please :

```
public class Location extends Activity {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    Marker mMarker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.location);
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        // mMap.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(36.755113, 3.058781) ,6) );

        CameraUpdate center =
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(36.755113,
                        3.058781));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo((float) 5.4);

        mMap.moveCamera(center);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      ));
    }

        public GoogleMap getMap() {
            return mMap;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have coarse or fine location permissions in manifest ?

Comment: Yes these two :  
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: So don't you see blue dot icon on map ?

Comment: no i dont , even when i click on the button of the localisation on the top

Comment: Check this SO question [34608517](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608517/map-setmylocationenabledtrue-not-working) and [26057833](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057833/android-google-maps-setmylocationenabledtrue) if it can help you;)